# Populate an object array

Tags: java, arrays, object, populate

I'm currently studying Java and not quite sure how to do this.

At the moment I have an employee class

```
public class employee {

private int empID;
private String empName;
private String job;

//constructors;

public employee(){
    this.empID = 0;
    this.empName = "";
    this.job = "";
}
public employee(int empID, String empName, String job){
    this.empID = empID;
    this.empName = empName;
    this. job = job;
}

//gets;

public int getEmpID(){
    return this.empID;
}
public String getEmpName(){
    return this.empName;
}
public String getJob(){
    return this.job;
}

//sets;

public void setEmpID(int empID){
    this.empID = empID;
}
public void setEmpName(String empName){
    this.empName = empName;
}
public void setJob(String job){
    this.job = job;
}
```

}

While in my main I created an object array of type employee with a size of 2 and then just increase the array count while letting the user enter some basic information and then another loop to print all the information entered.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class employeeArray {

public static void p(String s) {System.out.println(s);}

public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
    int empID, size=0, x=0;
    String empName;
    String job;
    employee [] employees = new employee[2];

    for(size = 0; size < 2; size++)
    {
        p("Employee "+(size+1));
        p("Please enter employee ID number: ");
        empID = k.nextInt(); k.nextLine();
        p("Please enter your name: ");
        empName = k.nextLine();
        p("Please enter your job role: ");
        job = k.nextLine();

        employees[size] = new employee();

        employees[size].setEmpID(empID);
        employees[size].setEmpName(empName);
        employees[size].setJob(job);


    }

    for(x=0; x<2;x++){
        p("Hello employee: "+employees[x].getEmpName()+" your job role is "+employees[x].getJob()+ 
                " your log in ID is 0800"+employees[x].getEmpID());
    }
}
```

}

I understand how to populate each instance of the object by input but say i wanted to increase the size from 2 to 20 but already have the first 10 'pre-entered' so then i could display the 10 i currently have but still allowed to enter 10 more.

ps. sorry for my long-winded question, blocks of code and poor/lack of terminology. I'm new to this.

Comment: I cannot understand your question. Could you explain it in other way?

Answer (score 7):

Don't bother using arrays when you need to dynamically resize them unless it's strictly necessary (and even in that case you could just convert through `ArrayList.toArray(..)`).

Use an `ArrayList<Employee>` instead thatn an `Employee[]`. You won't have to worry about the capacity, you won't have to worry about deleting and moving elements. It would also support generic containers.

As a side note: the naming convention of Java suggests to use `Capitalized` names for classes.

Comment: It would be better `List<Employee> lstEmployess = new ArrayList<Employee>()`. More info: [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i kinda understand what you are saying. The only thing is, object arrays is the learning topic so im trying to get my head around that for now, I actually want to hard code the size of the array to 20 and have 10 already pre entered and just add 10 more from user input

Comment: Just like Jack said, if you want an dynamic array in Java use an ArrayList. simple arrays are fixed-size. In your example you instantiated an array with the size of two. If you want to add more than two items to it you'd have to allocate a new array with the size of 3. Then copy the contents of the old array to the new array and place your third item in the array. Because that involves a lot of code (and possible mistakes) it's better to use the ArrayList. It does those things for you (and a bit smarter and more efficient to).

Answer (score 0):

A Java array (with a small "a" -- a `[]` object) is fixed size when created.  So if you create the array with 10 elements it will always have exactly 10 elements (though some of them may not have non-null values).  If you need to increase the size of the array beyond it's currently allocated size then good luck!!  .... Er, I mean you must allocate a new, larger array and then copy the contents of the smaller array into it.

Copying an array in this fashion is not all that inefficient, but it is awkward and error-prone, so there are several JDK classes (such as java.util.ArrayList) that can hold a variable-length list and manage the ugly stuff for you.  (Truth be told, in general these classes keep an internal array and copy it to a larger one when needed, just as you would, so they're no more efficient.  But they simplify coding and reduce errors, and that's the important point.)

Comment: Yeah i understand. I think i explained this all wrong. I made the array size 2 for an example. I want to hard code the array size to 20. have 10 pre entered but allowed me to enter 10 more to make up the 20

Answer (score 0):

First of all change the class name to `Employee` instead of `employee`. Stick with java naming conventions.
Now You should take advantage of java utility classes instead . for Example `ArrayList<Employee>`. `ArrayList` implements dynamically resizing array, which lets the user to insert as much amount of data within it without worrying about the current size of the internal `array` because `ArrayList` is there to take care of it. But before using `ArrayList` to store your `Employee` objects you need to override `equals` method in `Employee` because `ArrayList` internally uses this method to find out the existence of look a like object in some methods. The `equals` method looks as follows within `Employee` class:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object anObject) 
{
    if (this == anObject) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof Employee) 
    {
        Employee anotherEmployee = (Employee)anObject;
        if ((this.toString()).equals(anotherEmployee.toString()))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
@Override
public String toString()//Override it so that it could be easier to compare two objects of Employee using toString()
{
    return empID+","+empName+","+job;
}
```

Now , You can use `ArrayList` in following way:

```
List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
for(size = 0; size < 2; size++)
    {
        p("Employee "+(size+1));
        p("Please enter employee ID number: ");
        empID = k.nextInt(); k.nextLine();
        p("Please enter your name: ");
        empName = k.nextLine();
        p("Please enter your job role: ");
        job = k.nextLine();

        Employee employee = new Employee();

        employee.setEmpID(empID);
        employee.setEmpName(empName);
        employee.setJob(job);
        list.add(employee);
    }

   for(int i = 0 ;i < list.size() ; i++){
    Employee employee = list.get(i);
    p("Hello employee: "+employee.getEmpName()+" your job role is "+employee.getJob()+ 
            " your log in ID is 0800"+employee.getEmpID());
}
```

Comment: Yeah i understand. But, I think i explained this all wrong. I made the array size 2 for an example. I want to hard code the array size to 20. and do now wish to resize it, have 10 pre entered employees but allowing me to enter 10 more to make up the 20. Sorry for the confusion i explained it horribly

Comment: @NiallConaghan: Do you want to enforce the user to fill those 20 employees before proceeding further? I gues I still couldn't get your point.

Comment: Humm, really what my trying to get at is; i want 20 employees. but 10 of these employees to have information about them already (ID number, name, job) then, allow the user to be able to add more employees if they want. So 20 employees. 10 of which already id number, name and job. and when you run the program it promps the user to add another empolyee which will be number 11

Answer (score 0):

According to you comments you actually don't want a dynamic array but one with a fixed size of 20 and 10 entered in it.

Example:

```
int[] intArray = new int[20];

intArray[0] = 1
intArray[1] = 2
intArray[2] = 3
intArray[3] = 4
intArray[4] = 5
intArray[5] = 6
intArray[6] = 7
intArray[7] = 8
intArray[8] = 9
intArray[9] = 10

//now to fill the rest of the slots.
for(int i = 10; i < intArray.length; i++) {
    intArray[i] = i + 1;
}
```

However you'll be the one that's responsible for keeping track what is in the array and what is not and you cant add more than 20 items to the array.

Edit:
You edited your post. With the above code you could do what you want. If you really want to dynamically increase your array without using an ArrayList you could use System#arrayCopy

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object, int, java.lang.Object, int, int)

It lets you copy your existing array to a new (empty) array with the new size.

Comment: Yes exactly, boy i really need to learn how to word my problems correctly. So your filling a fixed array with the numbers 1 - 10. I want to fill 10 employees with the an ID number, name and job. how would i go about doing that? like employee[1] = (567, John, Programmer); and so on?